# using match function to pick out phone numbers from stored data

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following code to match phone numbers and store them in variable "phone". however it also matches dates as phone numbers. for example, if I give it the following string:
`html.Code = 'call us at 517-156-4435 on the date 2002-01-23'` the following match function saves both `'517-156-4435'` & `'2002-01-23'`. how would I adjust the code so it only saves the `'517-156-4435'` number?

```
phone = htmlCode.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]{2,}/)[0];
```

I had no idea what other steps to take to troubleshoot this issue, I'm just starting out learning javascript so anything helps.

Comment: do u know anything about regex? u used a quite complex quantifier there with {2,} so I guess u understand why + will match any number of digits above zero

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to `[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}`

You are using the `{2,}` means between 2 and infinite. So `2002-01-23` has two digits (23) and therefore matches it.

Assuming your phone number would always be in the format of `012-345-6789`, then `[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can try `/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2,}/`.

PS: this is not a `javascript` you use here, but `regex`. Here is useful site to try regexes out - https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

It requires a pattern matching of `3 numerical values followed by - followed by 3 numerical values followed by - followed by 4 numerical values`.

```js
const paragraph = 'call us at 517-156-4435 on the date 2002-01-23';
  const regex = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g
  const found = paragraph.match(regex)[0];
  
  console.log(found);
```

```
  \d{3} Matches exactly three digits.
  - Matches a hyphen.
  \d{3} Matches exactly three digits.
  - Matches another hyphen.
  \d{4} Matches exactly four digits.
```